# How to link ListenableFuture callback with running another ListenableFuture?

Tags: java, concurrency, guava

I have situation when I need to link ListanableFuture callback execution with invoking another ListanableFuture:

```
 public void foo(MyObject o)
   ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   final ListenableFuture<T> future1 = //....;
   callback.addListener(new Runnable(() -> {
          try{
            System.out.println("future1 callback started");
          }finally {
            if(someCondition){
              lock.unlock();
            }
          }
      }), executor);
      if(someCondition){
        ListenableFuture<T> future2 = 
             MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(executor).submit(
                () -> {
                   lock.lock();
                   //This future should be triggered after finishing 
                    callback for future1.
                   return null;
               }
            );
        o.future = future2;
        }
 }

 public void bar(){
    MyObject o = //.....;
    foo(o);
    if(o.future2){
      o.addListener(some custom logic);
    }
 }
```

As you can see I solved it with ReentrantLock but frankly speaking I haven't tested it yet and I'm not sure if there is cleaner way how to do that.
Please help.

**UPDATE**
I made some updates - so my point is to be able to somehow in method bar execute some custom logic after finishing callback in method foo.

Comment: Just submit in the callback. You have a race hazard in your current code - it won't work. Alternatively throw this away and use `CompletableFuture` that has a more sophisticated API and supports chaining out of the box. For example - propagating errors manually is actually not trivial - and if you don't your application will just hang without explanation.

Comment: Im not sure if I completely understood you, but the problem here will be if I submit it in the callback then I might not be able to add listener to this future in other place.

Comment: This is exactly what is termed ["Callback Hell"](http://callbackhell.com/) - I wouldn't try and write new code using the paradigm. But given that unless the first future completes the second is never submitted then adding listeners to it is meaningless - they would go in the callback too.

Comment: I updated initial example to make it cleaner.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I would lovely refactor that to CompletableFuture but unfortunately this logic is already in place and I'm afraid that I might brake it. For me the main goal is to add some listener in method bar to execute it after future1 callback finished.

Comment: or probably what you meant is that instead of creating future2 as ListenableFuture I could create CompletableFuture and and set it into MyObject? So that in bar method I could use thenRunAsync instead of adding listener

Comment: [This documentation](https://github.com/krka/java8-future-guide) might be of help to you.